# VNCServer fails to start with error: couldn't find "/bin/vncpasswd"

Tags: vnc, oracle-linux

I'm using Linux with below specifications :

- Virtualization: VMWare
- Operating System: Oracle Linux Server 7.4
- CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:oracle:linux:7:4:server
- Kernel: Linux 4.1.12-94.3.9.el7uek.x86_64

Command `vncserver` gives error:

```
vncserver: couldn't find "/bin/vncpasswd"
```

I tried

```
yum remove vnc
yum remove vnc-server
yum install tigervnc-server xorg-x11-fonts-Type1
```

How can I resolve this? In case I accidentally removed it (I cannot say for sure), can I somehow get it back?

Comment: reinstall the package

Comment: how? i am new to this stuff.

Comment: i tried # yum remove vnc
yum remove vnc-server
and installed them

Comment: Did you try `sudo vncserver`?